is subjective idealism or solipsism debunked because of the existence of "Brain" and "Surprise"? related to mind- body problem
reading this might help you understand my point
Idealism, Narrative and the Mind-Brain Relation
https://www.jstor.org/stable/44807008
how does someone like Berkeley explain the fact that there is something,(the brain), in the world that the mind created that can not only affect the mind itself if manipulated (with medicine or drugs for example) but completely correlates with mind's activity and can explain or even predict its behavior?
also how can we get "Surprised" if we are the one creating our own world? for example in dream once we realize we are in a dream, we can manipulate our dream (lucid dreaming) so in short 'Surprise' should be impossible in a lucid dream
but in real world that doesn't happen
you might try to argue that even in lucid dream one can get surprised by one's identity and choices in a dream, but i would say that surprise happens because your "self" or "will" is outside of the dream and is connected to the real world (a little similar to Schopenhauer's metaphysics)
the point being there is something beside the dream, something your mind can't control, that's why you can get surprised by it's behavior
but in a true solipsistic worldview 'surprise' should be impossible

Our mind is not the mind that created our world for Berkeley, the mind of God did. That God can surprise us is hardly surprising. And even if it was "us" conjuring up the world, the "self" need not be connected to the "real world" to be 'outside' of its current focus either - surprise. It is also hardly surprising that two conjurings, the brain and the mind's self-image, can correlate, even perfectly, seeing how they have a common cause. These types of naive objections are not fit for any debunking.

@Conifold "if it was 'us' conjuring up the world, the 'self' need not be connected to the 'real world' to be 'outside' of its current focus either" this is the part that you need to prove here

The debunking is your argument, if you want to make it it is you who needs to 'prove' the opposite. "I would say... is connected to the real world" only begs the question. "Real world explains it, therefore, this is how it must be" is no better. And Freudian observations and dissociative personalities make it facially very plausible, so you have your work cut out for you.

@Conifold my argument is if you have made the world you are basically god, you have the total knowledge on the thing you created out of thin air, so you should have total control over this world, but we don't, so there must be something outside of our mind to cause us to get surprised, and you said "if it was 'us' conjuring up the world, the 'self' need not be connected to the 'real world' to be 'outside' of its current focus either", you used an argument with a premise i don't see as justified yet, so no it's your job to provide prove to counter my argument

"If you have made the world you are basically god, you have the total knowledge on the thing you created" is not an argument, it is an assertion, and an implausible one at that. The rest just falls apart.

@Conifold if you want to argue a god can get surprised be my guest but that's a dumb argument nonetheless

God is omnipotent, so he easily can get surprised if he so chooses, but you are getting ahead of yourself. You first need to get from creating "the world" to being God, where "the world" is not the grand cosmos of realism, but only sporadic shreds the self actually encounters. And then to get from creating that to "total knowledge" of it when "the left hand does not know what the right hand is doing" is a proverb. Or, to put it Kant's way, when the empirical self is not even equipped to know the noumenal self. You are overly impressed by monotheistic doctrines of glorified Creator.

@Conifold god is omnipotent so he can choose to get surprised is basically the old philosophical question that "can god create a rock so heavy that he can't lift?", you seems to think that he can but i'm not too sure about that, now that's a debate to be had and probably will come up in this conversation but right now the omnipotent part is irrelevant we are talking about omniscient part, can you get surprised if you are omniscient? my answer is no. knowledge can only exist inside a world, it's always a knowledge of something, if you made this world that means you also made it's knowledge

@Conifold i don't fully understand this part of your comment, can you clarify? "You first need to get from creating "the world" to being God, where "the world" is not the grand cosmos of realism, but only sporadic shreds the self actually encounters.",  also what you said about noumena wouldn't help you because kant isn't a solipsist

@Conifold if by "You first need to get from creating "the world" to being God, where "the world" is not the grand cosmos of realism, but only sporadic shreds the self actually encounters." you meant this is just the world you see and that there can be some other world out there, this argument is actually in my favor and not yours since that proves there was something outside of your mind, in order for solipsism to work you need to work within the framework of "this world being the only world that there is"

We do not see the grand cosmos, not much of anything, in fact. The rest may well be small scale self-tales. "Something outside" is just circular.
